# Reading HTML content from Clipboard in Delphi

Tags: delphi, clipboard, clipboarddata

I have a webpage which has various tables on it.  These tables are Javascript components, not just pure HTML tables. I need to process the text of this webpage (somewhat similar to screen scraping) with a Delphi program (Delphi 10.3).

I do a <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to select all the webpage and copy everything to the clipboard. If I paste this into a `TMemo` component in my program, I am only getting text outside the table.  If I paste into MS Word, I can see all the content, including the text inside the table.

I can paste this properly into `TAdvRichEditor` (3rd party), but it takes forever, and I often run out of memory.  This leads me to believe that I need to directly read the clipboard with an HTML clipboard format.

I set up a clipboard HTML format.  When I inspect the clipboard contents, I get what looks like all Kanji characters.

How do I read the contents of the clipboard when the contents are HTML?

In a perfect world, I would like ONLY the text, not the HTML itself, but I can strip that out later.  Here is what I am doing now...

On initialization.. (where `CF_HTML` is a global variable)

```
CF_HTML := RegisterClipboardFormat('HTML Format');
```

then my routine is...

```
function TMain.ClipboardAsHTML: String;
var
  Data: THandle;
  Ptr: PChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  with Clipboard do
  begin
    Open;
    try
      Data := GetAsHandle(CF_HTML);
      if Data <> 0 then
      begin
        Ptr := PChar(GlobalLock(Data));
        if Ptr <> nil then
        try
          Result := Ptr;
        finally
          GlobalUnlock(Data);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Close;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

** ADDITIONAL INFO - When I copy from the webpage...  I can then inspect the contents of the Clipboard buffer using a free tool called InsideClipBoard.  It shows that the clipboard contains 1 entry, with 5 formats: `CT_TEXT`, `CF_OEMTEXT`, `CF_UNICODETEXT`, `CF_LOCALE`, and `'HTML Format'` (with Format ID of 49409).  Only `'HTML Format'` contains what I am looking for.... and that is what I am trying to access with the code that I have shown.

Comment: The problem is that when you use CTRL+A and then CTRL+C to copy the contents of a webpage the contents aren't saved in Clipboard as HTML. Well at least no based on `Clipbrd.exe` which is a Clipboard viewer that was available in WindowsXP. Yes you can copy this file to Windows 7 and it still works. But from what I have read it doesn't work on Windows 10. Any way based on information from `Clibrd.exe` the contents of a webpage are saved to clipboard in Text, Unicode Text, Locale and OEM Text formats....

Comment: ... Locale format is the one that is stored in binary form and is probably causing all those Kanji looking characters. Any way why don't you save the webpage from your browser in plain HTML format. This might force the browser to replace the JavaScript generated tables into plain HTML tables which you can process easily.

Comment: Start with some debugging. Dig deeper. Inspect the clipboard. What does it actually contain.

Comment: @@David - I added some additional info to my question.  The data is in the clipboard, in 'HTML Format', but I can't figure out how to access it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The HTML format is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/html-clipboard-format). It is placed on the clipboard as UTF-8 encoded text, and you can extract it like this.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows,
  Vcl.Clipbrd;

procedure Main;
var
  CF_HTML: Word;
  Data: THandle;
  Ptr: Pointer;
  Error: DWORD;
  Size: NativeUInt;
  utf8: UTF8String;
  Html: string;
begin
  CF_HTML := RegisterClipboardFormat('HTML Format');

  Clipboard.Open;
  try
    Data := Clipboard.GetAsHandle(CF_HTML);
    if Data=0 then begin
      Writeln('HTML data not found on clipboard');
      Exit;
    end;

    Ptr := GlobalLock(Data);
    if not Assigned(Ptr) then begin
      Error := GetLastError;
      Writeln('GlobalLock failed: ' + SysErrorMessage(Error));
      Exit;
    end;
    try
      Size := GlobalSize(Data);
      if Size=0 then begin
        Error := GetLastError;
        Writeln('GlobalSize failed: ' + SysErrorMessage(Error));
        Exit;
      end;

      SetString(utf8, PAnsiChar(Ptr), Size - 1);
      Html := string(utf8);
      Writeln(Html);
    finally
      GlobalUnlock(Data);
    end;
  finally
    Clipboard.Close;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```